# Function to return any string value in a cell to a new row according to the length of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Right now I have this table:

```
Names
----------
Bill
James
----------
```

My aim here is to insert these names repeatedly into new rows according to their lengths.

For example

```
Names
----------
Bill
Bill
Bill
Bill
James
James
James
James
James
```

P.S. I am going to find out whether there is a way of dealing with it with only filters like `where`, `having`...etc or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long could a name be? A `WHERE` can't *create* more rows though, only filter them. You'll need to use something like a Tally to achieve this.

Comment: A tally table would indeed be the preferable set-based method, have added an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select name, len(name) as n
      from t
      union all
      select name, n - 1
      from cte
      where n > 1
     )
select cte.name
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2a3168c413bc4aeb1ec7204d189bac1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Note, if the OP has values much longer rather than 5 characters, a set based approach will be significantly faster than an iterative one like this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most performant way to do this is to use a `numbers/tally table`

Simulating a tally table here called `digits` - this would ideally be a permanent table storing numbers from 1 to a bajillion, or whatever you need.

```
with digits as (
  select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))v(n)
),
T as (
  select 'Bill' [Name] union all select 'James'
)
select t.[Name] 
from T
cross apply digits d
where d.n <= Len(T.[name])
```